# Extract images from PDF using python PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, image-processing, reportlab, pypdf

Is there any way to extract images as stream from pdf document (using [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2) library)? 
Also is it possible to replace some images to another (generated with PIL for example or loaded from file)?

I'm able to get EncodedStreamObject from pdf objects tree and get encoded stream (by calling getData() method), but looks like it just raw content w/o any image headers and other meta information.

```py
>>> import PyPDF2
>>> # sample.pdf contains png images
>>> reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('sample.pdf', 'rb'))
>>> reader.resolvedObjects[0][9]
{'/BitsPerComponent': 8,
'/ColorSpace': ['/ICCBased', IndirectObject(20, 0)],
'/Filter': '/FlateDecode',
'/Height': 30,
'/Subtype': '/Image',
'/Type': '/XObject',
'/Width': 100}
>>>
>>> reader.resolvedObjects[0][9].__class__
PyPDF2.generic.EncodedStreamObject
>>>
>>> s = reader.resolvedObjects[0][9].getData()
>>> len(s), s[:10]
(9000, '\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc')
```

I've looked across [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2), [ReportLab](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab) and [PDFMiner](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/) solutions quite a bit, but haven't found anything like what I'm looking for.

Any code samples and links will be very helpful.

Comment: So you want to open a large pdf, extract a page(s), and add that page(s) to an existing pdf? Would it be ok to save that combined pdf as a new file?

Comment: This answer could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34116472/1513933

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract images from PDF without resampling, in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693820/extract-images-from-pdf-without-resampling-in-python)

Comment: PyPDF2 became deprecated. Use `pypdf`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import fitz
doc = fitz.open(filePath)
for i in range(len(doc)):
    for img in doc.getPageImageList(i):
        xref = img[0]
        pix = fitz.Pixmap(doc, xref)
        if pix.n < 5:       # this is GRAY or RGB
            pix.writePNG("p%s-%s.png" % (i, xref))
        else:               # CMYK: convert to RGB first
            pix1 = fitz.Pixmap(fitz.csRGB, pix)
            pix1.writePNG("p%s-%s.png" % (i, xref))
            pix1 = None
        pix = None
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: thanks @jainam shah  it works for me. `pip install PyMuPDF` install this library and `import fitz` after it works.

Answer (score 2):

### Extracting Images from PDF

1. This code helps to fetch any images in scanned or machine generated
   pdf or normal pdf
2. determines its occurrence example how many images in each page
3. Fetches images with same resolution and extension

```
pip install PyMuPDF
import fitz
import io
from PIL import Image
#file path you want to extract images from
file = r"File_path"
#open the file
pdf_file = fitz.open(file)   
#iterate over PDF pages
    for page_index in range(pdf_file.page_count):
        #get the page itself
        page = pdf_file[page_index]
        image_li = page.get_images()
        #printing number of images found in this page
        #page index starts from 0 hence adding 1 to its content
        if image_li:
            print(f"[+] Found a total of {len(image_li)} images in page {page_index+1}")
        else:
            print(f"[!] No images found on page {page_index+1}")
        for image_index, img in enumerate(page.get_images(), start=1):
            #get the XREF of the image
            xref = img[0]
            #extract the image bytes
            base_image = pdf_file.extract_image(xref)
            image_bytes = base_image["image"]
            #get the image extension
            image_ext = base_image["ext"]
            #load it to PIL
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
            #save it to local disk
            image.save(open(f"image{page_index+1}_{image_index}.{image_ext}", "wb"))
     
         

`
```

Answer (score 2):

As PyPDF2 became deprecated in the mean time, go to pypdf.

### Extract images

Straight [from the docs](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-images.html):

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")

page = reader.pages[0]
count = 0

for image_file_object in page.images:
    with open(str(count) + image_file_object.name, "wb") as fp:
        fp.write(image_file_object.data)
        count += 1
```

### Replace images

Will go into the docs soon: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/pull/1894

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter
reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()
for page in reader.pages:
    writer.add_page(page)
for page in writer.pages:
    for img in page.images:
        img.replace(img.image, quality=80)
with open("out.pdf", "wb") as f:
    writer.write(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Image metadata is not stored within the encoded images of a PDF. If metadata is stored at all, it is stored in PDF itself, but stripped from the underlying image. The metadata you see in your example is likely all that you'll be able to get. It's possible that PDF encoders may store image metadata elsewhere in the PDF, but I haven't seen this. (Note this metadata question [was also asked for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5653826/234270).)

It's definitely possible to extract the stream however, as you mentioned, you use the `getData` operation.

As for replacing it, you'll need to create a new image object with the PDF, add it to the end, and update the indirect Object pointers accordingly. It will be difficult to do this with PyPdf2.